# How to get onItemHoverListener behavior with listView items to catch event from Explore by touch?

Tags: android, android-listview, accessibility

My primary goal is to know which item in my listView is focused with an accessibility focus by the Explore by touch.

Because I'm working on an application, I can't have access to the accessibility service methods for this behavior.

The best thing would be to have an onItemHoverListener like onItemClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemHoverListener(new OnItemHoverListener(){

    public void onItemHover(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
         //Can know here which item is focused by Explore by touch
         //Can get the position of this item in my listview
    }

});
```

What else can I do to get this behavior?

Comment: There might be a more general solution. What are you trying to accomplish by knowing which item has accessibility focus? Also, what is the lowest API level that you're targeting?

Comment: I want to get the position of the focused item by Explore by touch in my listView. I don't have any constraint about the lowest API, meaning that I can target only the most recent API if I need.

Comment: Right, but what are you going to do with the position? I ask because Explore by Touch is a feature that's usually intended to be invisible to the application -- exploring shouldn't trigger any side effects like changes to the UI or additional app-generated speech.

Comment: I want to save the position for a custom iterator that loop my listView. Putting the focus by touch on an item should impact my iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can observe accessibility focus changes by watching for TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED events, either by overriding onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent on a parent view or setting an AccessibilityDelegate on a parent view that overrides this method.

```
myListView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new MyDelegate());
```

Where the delegate is defined as something like:

```
class MyDelegate extends AccessibilityDelegate {
    ...

    public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup host, View child,
            AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (host == myListView) {
            int childPosition = myListView.getPositionForView(child);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getChildIndex doesn't exist but getPositionForView(Child) give me what I want without the need of the substraction with firstVisiblePosition and childIndex. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Simplified to use that API.